# Navigation Controller Title

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a navigation controller and i set the title in the viewDidLoad like so:

```
self.title = @"My View Controller";
```

But a name like that is too long to fit in the tab bar name down below. How do i change the tab bar name without changing the title displayed on the navigation bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct, you can set them separately. If you are adding view controllers to the tab bar, you can do something like:

`thisViewController.title = @"Name of this view controller";` (or self.title in your case)

and then for the title at the top, after have `self.navigationItem.title = @"Title at top";`?

Comment: It comes back with an error that says "Request for member 'title' in something not a structure or union."

Comment: Edited my answer, sorry about that, it should be `myViewController.title` or self.title, whatever, the main part is `self.navigationItem.title`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the tabBarItem property of the tabBarController of your tab bar. That's the correct way to go.